# How to add new line character in the cell comment using apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I need to add Multiple lines in a cell Comment. How to break the line in cell Comment using apache POI

Ex:

```
Comment = "This is comment 1";
comment = comment + "This is comment2";
comment = comment + "This is comment3";
cell.setCellComment(comment);
```

Comment: Did you try adding newlines? `"This is comment 1\n"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use \n for a new line.

```
Comment = "This is comment 1";
comment = comment + "\n This is comment2";
comment = comment + "\n This is comment3";
cell.setCellComment(comment);
```